# Checking if future time (epoch milliseconds) is within 3 hours of current time (epoch milliseconds)

Tags: java

I am trying to compare two times to see if a future time is within the next 3 hours of current time.

Below is some code that I have tried where I tried taking the future time minus 10,800,000 and if the current time is greater than or equal to the difference it should return true. I do not know if 10,800,000 is the correct thing to use though since sometimes it is returning true/false when it should now.

```
  public static Boolean checkIfWithin3Hours(long startTime, long currentTime){
           if(currentTime >= startTime - (10800000)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
  }
```

I would expect it to return true if the epoch time in milliseconds is within 3 hours of the future time in ms.

Comment: I figured it out, guess me typing it out and explaining it made me realize what I was doing wrong. Had the two times in the wrong spot.

Comment: `TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(3)` to convert hours to Milliseconds.

Comment: If you only know two epochs, then `3 * 60 * 60 * 1000` is a good enough estimate for whether there are 3 hours inbetween two stamps. If you also know the time zone, you'll compute in, you could use `ZonedDateTime` objects, and `HOURS.between(start, current) >= 3`. That way it's a lot more clear what you want.

Comment: Whether you compare with 3*60*60*100 or number of hours it is same. Since you are passing currentTime and startTime both as inputs it will always give you a deterministic result for a given input. There is no date involved in your function, just you are comparing long values. Can you share an example input where you have observed random output?

Comment: This Question is confused. Can’t you state your business logic one simple sentence? Tip: Clearly defining your goal in plain English will help lead the way to clear code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Your Question is confusing, not clear on exact details of your business logic. But this should get you pointed in the right direction.

```
Instant
.ofEpochSecond( … )
.minus(
    Duration
    .ofHours( 3 ) 
)
.isBefore( 
    Instant.now()
)
```

## *java.time*

We have classes for this. Do not roll-your-own date-time solution.

## `Instant`

Get the current moment in UTC.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
```

## `Duration`

Specify your wait time as a `Duration`, a span of time unattached to the timeline.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofHours( 3 ) ;
```

Specify your start time. You did not explain, but apparently the starting moment was given to you as a count of whole seconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z. Paste that number as an `Instant`.

```
Instant start = Instant.ofEpochSecond( 10_800_000L ) ;
```

Add our duration to determine the moment of our target.

```
Instant limit = start.plus( d ) ;
```

Compare to current moment.

```
Boolean pastLimit = now.isAfter( limit ) ;
```

Tip: Do not track time as a mere integer. Doing so is confusing and error-prone, making debugging difficult.  Use appropriate data types. Pass `Instant` objects around your code, not a count-of-seconds.

## `Interval`

Alternatively, get fancier with an additional library.

Add the *ThreeTen-Extra* library to your project. We want to use the `Interval` class that represents a span of time attached to the timeline as a pair of `Instant` objects.

Add the duration to the starting `then` moment.

```
Interval interval = Interval.of( then , then.plus( d ) ;
```

Test if the current moment is within that interval.

```
Boolean nowInInterval = interval.contains( now ) ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed response. I learned a lot from it!

Answer (score 1):

```
1000 milliseconds/second
60 seconds/minute
60 minutes/hour
3 hours
```

Multiply it all together and you get 10,800,000 milliseconds. First step, your number is correct.

Next step, calculate whether the number is in the range:

If timeTesting is in the range of 3 hours from now, timeNow <= timeTesting <= timeNow + 10,800,000 ms.

Second step, your range test is incorrect.

Fix it with the following:

```
public static Boolean checkIfWithin3Hours(long startTime, long currentTime){
    return startTime <= currentTime && currentTime <= startTime + 10800000;
}
```